# Splitting a social network into 2 based on node type with igraph (R)

Tags: r, igraph, social-networking

How would I go about splitting this social network into 2, based on node colour?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnkBF.jpg

I already have the dataset with the information on the nodes, but I'm unsure how to split them with igraph.

Code:

```
# Weighted 
V(network)[attrib_info$sex =="M"]$color="tomato2"
V(network)[attrib_info$sex =="F"]$color="lightblue2"
plot.igraph(network,
            vertex.size=10,
            vertex.label.cex=0.0000000000000000001,
            edge.color="black",
            edge.width=E(network)$weight*20)
```

Comment: Just to confirm what you are asking:  Do you want two separate networks - one with each type of vertex? In your case, one network for sex=M and one for sex=F?

Comment: Yes, apologies for the clunky wording - I'm quite new to R and completely new to igraph. Also, if possible, I would like to have the corresponding nodes be in the same position from the initial graph to the two separate ones, so that in a figure showing all three it would be obvious that the last two are derived from the first. I say this because so far in using R, it seems to plot a random orientation every time I run the plot command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do that,  you need to take control of the layout. That is not hard to do. Since you do not provide your data, I will illustrate using the standard `karate` data set. I set the random seed to get reproducible results. Then, generate a layout. The karate network comes with a `color` attribute for the vertices and we want to split the network based on this attribute.

```
library(igraph)
library(igraphdata)     ## for karate
data(karate)

set.seed(2021)
LO = scale(layout_nicely(karate))
plot(karate, layout=LO, rescale=F, vertex.size=20,
    xlim=0.8*range(LO[,1]), ylim=0.8*range(LO[,2]))
```

[image: karate network]

Notice that I saved the layout in order to get reproducible positions for all of the vertices. But there is something else going on here that warrants discussion:  my use of rescale, xlim and ylim. By default, igraph rescales the layout to the range [-1,1]. We want the same positions for all three graphs, so we turn that off with rescale=F. However, igraph *still* plots only the range from -1 to 1 unless you set xlim and ylim, so I pick a range that will show all of the nodes without excessive whitespace around the graph.

Now we want to break out the two subnetworks by color.

```
OV = which(V(karate)$color == 1)
BV = which(V(karate)$color == 2)
orange = induced_subgraph(karate, OV)
blue   = induced_subgraph(karate, BV)
```

Finally,  we want to plot all three on the same graph with the nodes in the same positions. Basically, that is repeating the above plot statement for each of the three networks, selecting just the relevant parts of the layout matrix for each network.  I use `par` to make three graphs on one screen. (And of course, I resized the screen to make it fit these nicely.)

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3), mar = c(1,2,1,2))
plot(karate, layout=LO, rescale=F, vertex.size=20,
    xlim=0.9*range(LO[,1]), ylim=0.85*range(LO[,2]))
plot(orange, layout=LO[OV, ], rescale=F, vertex.size=20,
    xlim=0.9*range(LO[,1]), ylim=0.85*range(LO[,2]))
plot(blue, layout=LO[BV, ], rescale=F, vertex.size=20,
    xlim=0.9*range(LO[,1]), ylim=0.85*range(LO[,2]))
```

[image: Three networks]